# How should I provision for a 30,000-listener Shoutcast stream?

Tags: vps, bandwidth, streaming

My client wants to run a one-off live podcast on his blog, which is popular enough to land a couple million visits per month. Am I right in imagining that ShoutCast is the best way to handle that?

More importantly, what kind of VPS would we need to serve up to 30k listeners a modest-quality stream?

Comment: "one-off live podcast" and "visits per month" does not compute, unless this podcast is going to be very, *very* long.

Comment: It might be that the blog is already very popular and gets the couple million visits per month, now he's going to add a one-off podcast.

Comment: This question was closed because shopping recommendations are outside of the scope of Server Fault. [Please ensure you are familiar with the FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq#questions).

Answer (score 1):

You need about 2gbps of bandwidth at 64kbps per client. I doubt your average VPS will do more than 100mbps.

Perhaps load balancing across a few EC2 instances will work for you.